# Node.JS Memory problem, Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: node.js, heroku, sharp

I'm having some memory problems running my Node.JS API on heroku (with a RAM limit of 512mb). Heroku logs the following:

> 2020-08-03T11:31:41.084066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running
> mem=950M(185.6%)
>
> 2020-08-03T11:31:41.086357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory
> quota exceeded)

This happens on a request that among some other small tasks:

- Sends an image encoded in base64
- Creates a buffer from that image
- Processes the image through "sharp" module three times (needed for checking if the image is vertical and then creating 2 different images)
- Resize the image one time to big pixel dimensions (i.e. 10000x7000px)
- Uploads the images to an FTP server.

The images I'm working with are large print images(more than 1000x1000px).

I can post samples of the code if you think is necessary but do you know if this computing should be able to run on a 512mb capped ram server on Heroku? Or maybe I have some memory leak on my code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I was able to suppress it drastically by disabling caching by calling `sharp.cache(false)`. An example snippet would look like this:

```js
const sharp = require('sharp');
sharp.cache(false);

// then do your sharp magic
```

You can find more information about cache in [sharp docs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-utility#cache).

Here's the drop of the memory usage I noticed after releasing with the cache disabled. Still, there's an unreleased portion of memory, but the situation is much better than what it was.

[image]

[As per this thread in sharp's github issues](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/349#issuecomment-184614194), the cache doesn't improve the performance significantly unless you process the same image in close succession. Therefore, if your application does not expect the same image to be processed in such a way, you might be able to see a memory usage improvement.

**More..**

Also, apparently, [there is a memory fragmentation problem](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/955) due to the way memory is allocated when sharp processes images using libuv threads on Linux. [There's a heroku buildpack](https://github.com/gaffneyc/heroku-buildpack-jemalloc) which configures heroku dynos to use an alternative memory allocator called `jemalloc` which reduces memory fragmentation. Although I didn't personally see a noticeable improvement by using this, you can give it a try and see if it works for you.